# Why do I get 'Handshake timed out'? How can I configure timeout period?

Tags: scala, akka

I am new in Akka actors and I am doing some tests. Suppose I have actors performing long running tasks like following:

```
 override def receive = {

    case email: Email => /*Future*/ {

        Thread sleep 3000

    }

 }
```

I ran a stress test (remote actos on another machine in network) and I receive the following error:

akka.remote.EndpointAssociationException: Association failed with [akka.tcp://EmailSystem@192.168.1.6:5000]
Caused by: akka.remote.transport.AkkaProtocolException: No response from remote. Handshake timed out

How can I configure this to don't get this error again? Should I use a future in the receive method instead of normal code (as on comment above)? What is the impact of doing that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's a really bad idea to have an actor that blocks for a long time like that, since it cannot respond to messages and additionally the akka default threadpool is one thread per core of your computer so you might also be stopping other actors from processing any messages.

Fork that blocking job on a separate execution context/thread pool instead (and make sure to limit how many threads there is in that threadpool). You can then notify the actor using pipeTo:

```
import akka.pattern.pipe

case email: Email => 
  val futureEmail = Future {
     ... send email and then ...
     EmailSent()
  }
  futureEmail pipeTo sender
```

Comment: Future() takes an implicit ExecutionContext as its second parameter list so that is where you can provide a thread pool that limits how many concurrent email processes you allow.